# Error loading syntax file when launch the sublime

Tags: django, sublimetext

> Error loading syntax file "Packages/Djaneiro/Syntaxes/Python
>   Django.tmLanguage": Error parsing plist xml: Failed to open file In
>   file "Packages/Djaneiro/Syntaxes/Python Django.tmLanguage"

After installed some **`plugins of sublime`**, this error occured when I launch the sublime again.
Can anyone solve the problem?

Comment: I've created an issue report on the project GitHub: https://github.com/squ1b3r/Djaneiro/issues/82

Answer (score 3):

1. **Uninstall.**

   CTRL + SHIFT + P

   Start typing "remove package" and select it.
2. **Reinstall.**

   CTRL + SHIFT + P

   Start typing "install package" and select it.

   Then, start typing "djaneiro" and select it.
3. **Restart SublimeText.**

Note: I have no idea why this happens, but it just happened to me, and that is how I resolved it.

Comment: Now it has happened to me multiple times. There must either be a bug in the plugin or SublimeText. One should not have to uninstall/reinstall a plugin on a regular basis...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have Djaneiro plugin installed, some of module like SetDjangoSyntax require this, and that's why you may have this error.

Comment: The error does't appear because the plugin is not installed. I am having the same issue and Djaneiro is installed a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall the package works also.

Answer (score 0):

i face this problem now, and just info : https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/error-loading-syntax-file-each-time-after-opening-st2/6474

we just need delete this file:

~/.config/sublime-text-3/Local/Session.sublime_session

- then restart your sublime, the bug has been fixed.